# Apache benchmark issue: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used. (windows)

Tags: apache, benchmarking

I want to benchmark my site and I found out that apache can do that for me with quite good statistics but unfortunately I fail. What I do is in my cmd prompt I navigate to `apache\bin` ( I'm on windows thus \ ) and run the following

```
ab -n 1000 -c 5 http://localhost/
```

What I get is:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1178079 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
bind: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used.   (730047)
```

Since I'm not really an expert I don't really know where to go from here.. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bumped into a very useful article, of course after asking a question.

Basically what I did was I had to open `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` with admin privileges and add

`::1             localhost`

below

`127.0.0.1       localhost`

Source: http://crossplatform.net/apachebench-localhost-bind-problem/